# Pelvic Floor muscles, how to tighten exercise

Tags: exercise

I am trying to understand the pelvic floor muscles as man in Section 2, how to exercise and articulate them. As they have many health benefits, and are more hidden muscles.

"Sit on a chair with your knees apart and tighten your pelvic floor muscles as if you were lifting your pelvic floor but not your buttocks off the chair." This seems different from section 1.

I thought the pelvic floor muscles is where you prevent flow of urine. So how is number 2 different from 1 below, or are they the same?

See article "Randomised controlled trial of pelvic floor muscle exercises and manometric biofeedback for ED"

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1324914/

1. In standing position

> Stand with your feet apart and tighten your pelvic floor muscles as if
> you were trying to stop the flow of urine and wind escaping. If you
> look in a mirror, you should be able to see the base of your penis
> move nearer to your abdomen and your testicles rise.
>
> Hold the contraction as strongly as you can.
>
> Try to avoid holding your breath, pulling in your abdomen or tensing
> your buttocks.
>
> Perform 3 maximal contractions in standing in the morning holding for
> __ seconds.
>
> Perform 3 maximal contractions in standing in the evening holding for
> __ seconds.

2. In sitting position

> Sit on a chair with your knees apart and tighten your pelvic floor
> muscles as if you were lifting your pelvic floor but not your buttocks
> off the chair.
>
> Hold the contraction as strongly as you can.
>
> Try to avoid holding your breath, pulling in your abdomen or tensing
> your buttocks.
>
> Perform 3 maximal contractions in sitting in the morning holding for
> ___ seconds.
>
> Perform 3 maximal contractions in sitting in the evening holding for
> ___ seconds

3. In lying position

> Lie on your back with your knees bent and your knees apart. Tighten
> your pelvic floor and hold the contraction as strongly as you can.
>
> Try to avoid pulling in your abdomen or tensing your buttocks.
>
> Perform 3 maximal contractions in lying in the morning holding for __
> seconds.
>
> Perform 3 maximal contractions in lying in the evening holding for __
> seconds.